# Multiple data binding properties on ASP.NET usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls

How can I have multiple properties in my usercontrol that can be databound? For a single property I have found that DefaultBindingProperty Attribute does the trick but I have no idea on how to get databinding with multiple properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had databind the usercontrol's 2 properties with the same eval expressions like below.

```
<uc3:PickDate ID="txtCutOffDate" runat="server" SelectedDate='<%# Eval("CutOffDate") %>'  Text='<%# Eval("CutOffDate") %>' RequiredField="False" TextBoxLength="100" ToolTipDate="CutoffDate"   ValidationGroup="UpdateVal" />
```

here cutoffdate was data field which bind with both selecteddate and text properties of pickdate control.

hope this helps!